# HBase alter table command fails with "ERROR: d != java.lang.String"

Tags: java, hbase, bigtable, opentsdb

HBase alter table command fails with

> ERROR: d != java.lang.String

, not sure where to look and how to debug that? Haven't found any HBase logs. I'm using OpenTSDB + Bigtable. 
Whenever I run alter command

> hbase(main):005:0> alter 'test_table', {NAME=>'colFam2',
>   property=>'1000'}

for my table it says:

> Nov 01, 2019 8:01:42 PM
>   com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl
>    INFO: [ManagedChannelImpl@4f94e] Created with target
>   bigtableadmin.googleapis.com:443
>
> ERROR: d != java.lang.String
>
> Here is some help for this command: Alter a table. ...

Comment: Please add your code here to better chance of getting help.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with a String format. It's super hard to debug hbase shell sessions, since hbase shell suppresses debug info.

dqlgnoleht@, the alter code can be found here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/a017a237fa8dae764451a658150190743c1b4127/quickstart/thirdparty/ruby/hbase/admin.rb#L536.  Basically, this is an `Admin.modifyTable` call.

This could be related to OpenTSDB's older version of the client, or it could be something else.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to understand what you're doing wrong if you posted your table structure and a precise query, but it appears to me, that an error

```
ERROR: d != java.lang.String
```

is thrown by a function

```
String.format("...%d...", ...);
```

when you run your alter. I suppose you should type the "property" value without any quotes

```
hbase(main):005:0> alter 'test_table', {NAME=>'colFam2', property=>1000}
```